# Bash script not copying files using udev

Tags: shell-script, udev

I have a script set up to run when a certain usb drive is inserted.  It is supposed to copy a folder from the usb drive into a backup folder, and write over this folder if it already exists.  However, when I plug in my usb drive, it creates the folder but it doesn't copy any files.

My .rules looks like this:

```
ACTION=="add", ATTR{idVendor}==Vendor, ATTR{idProduct}==Product, RUN+="/bin/sh /path/to/file/mkBackup"
```

My file mkBackup looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
a="/path/to/file/Backup"
if [ -e $a ]; then
        rm -rf $a
fi
mkdir $a
cp -r /path/to/usb/folder $a
```

When it is run by `udev`, the Backup folder is created but it is empty, but when I just run `./mkBackup`, the folder is created and everything is copied.  This is my first time using `udev` to do something like this, so please forgive me if this seems like a simple question.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the Backup folder is created, you know the script successfully executes when you plugin the device. I suspect that the script is executing **before** the device actually finishes mounting. Thus the files are not yet available for `cp`.

What happens if you add `sleep 5` after `mkdir $a` ? Or what if you try to copy existing files instead?

[This link](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html) is also pretty helpful as a reference.

I also use:

```
udevadm monitor --udev
```

To watch udev events in real time.

```
udevadm test /path/to/dev
```

To simulate a udev event run for the device. Note that this does **not** run any program specified by a RUN key.

**EDIT:** As Gilles helpfully points out, my idea won't work. And I'm not aware of a solution. Here's why:

Udev will make the USB device available to the OS. Then, the OS will realize that the OS contains a mountable file system and will mount it. At that point the files on the USB device are actually available.

Any script run by a udev rule will execute **before** the file system is actually mounted. If I think of an alternative I'll update the post.

Comment: Try this in your udev-rule `RUN+="/bin/sh -c /path/to/file/mkBackup"`

Comment: Adding the sleep line doesn't seem to help.  It makes it so the file manager doesn't open the window that opens when you normally plug in a usb drive (running ubuntu) on a delay.  I know it can copy over files though because it copies properly when I run the script manually.

Comment: @Bahamut This doesn't work either.

Comment: This is not going to help. Udev waits for the script to finish before it finishes its own job. The job of udev is to make the disk device available to the system. Until the disk device is available, a filesystem on the disk can't be mounted.

Comment: You might be able to work around the problem @Gilles pointed out by spawning a subprocess to wait before doing the backup -- something like `(sleep 5; cp -r /path/to/usb/folder $a) &`. BTW, I'd recommend using `rsync -a --delete` instead of deleting & recopying the folder. That way if something goes wrong, it won't have just auto-deleted your last good backup.

Comment: @GordonDavisson No, that wouldn't work because udev kills the process group that it forks once its child exists. The modern way to trigger something when a filesystem becomes available is via D-Bus notifications sent by Udisks.

Comment: can you show`ps -p 1 -o comm=` ?